# Probability of drawing exactly 2 balls of a same color from a bin

Tags: probability, solution-verification

There is a bin with 1 green ball, 1 red ball, 1 blue ball, and 1 yellow ball.

We draw 4 balls with replacement. What is the probability of drawing exactly 2 of a given color? Order doesn't matter, as long as we have exactly 2 balls drawn of a given color.

My attempt was as follows:

There are $\binom 4 2$ ways to select two "spots" in the 4 output spots. For each of those ways, the probability of having exactly two is $\frac 1 4 \cdot \frac 1 4 \cdot \frac 3 4 \cdot \frac 3 4$. Hence the final probability is just $\binom 4 2 \cdot \frac 1 4 \cdot \frac 1 4 \cdot \frac 3 4 \cdot \frac 3 4$.

Is this right?

Comment: Yes, this looks good.  You could also see this as an instance of the binomial distribution with success probability $\frac 14$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the 'given color' is Red. The probability of Red on any one draw is $1/4.$ Let $X$ be the number of times Red is drawn. Then $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=4, p=1/4).$ We seek $P(X=2) = 0.2109.$

```
dbinom(2, 4, .25)
[1] 0.2109375
```

According to this interpretation `RRYG`, `RBRY`, and `RYRY` all meet the condition.

However, if the
condition is that exactly two balls of any color are drawn, then `RRYG`, `GBBY` both count. That seems to be a harder problem. This may be a possible interpretation of the title, as it currently stands.

Comment: Sorry, the second list should have been something like `RRYG` and `GBBY`. Fixing the typo.